# Undefine data, but data us getting logged in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

Data is returning undefine after they were fetched from the backend. When I console.log it, the data get returned in the console. But when I try to use the data, it was returning undefine

```
        //Here is the my logic using axios but it didnot work, it keeps throwing 404 error and undefined data

    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
    import axios from "axios";

        const MyBaseQuery =
           ({ baseUrl } = { baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000" }) =>
           async ({ url, method, data }) => {
             try {
               const result = await axios({ url: baseUrl + url, method, data });
               return { data: result.data };
             } catch (axiosError) {
               let err = axiosError;
               return {
                 error: { status: err.response?.status, data: err.response?.data },
               };
             }
           };

         export const getAllCarsApi = createApi({
           reducerPath: "getAllCarsApi",
           baseQuery: MyBaseQuery,
           endpoints(build) {
             return {
               getAllCarsApi: build.query({
                 query: () => ({ url: "all-cars", method: "GET" }),
               }),
             };
           },
         });

         export const { useGetAllCarsQuery } = getAllCarsApi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by adding async and await in my functions.